Geolocalizacion Wordpress y Checkout
Tengo una tienda online de productos digitales y quiero vender a otros países. Ya implementé maxmind geo-localización en WordPress y el cambio de moneda con el plugin FOX Switch Currency, pero no funciona la geo-localización. Cuando una IP de México, supongamos, ingresa a la tienda online, no se cambia de moneda automáticamente.
Otra cosa que quiero realizar es que en el checkout se cambien los campos de datos que tiene que rellenar el cliente (nombre, apellido, email...etc): lo que quiero cambiar es el campo de facturación; yo tengo configurado para Argentina, y para Argentina se pide el DNI, pero para México es otro dato y quiero que ese campo se cambie cuando esta la tienda en moneda Mexicana.
Gracias!

La descripción de tu problema está bien, pero debieras incluir la parte relevante del código que estás utilizando en la pregunta. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderla. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Aprovecho para comentar que, en tu pregunta anterior recibiste una respuesta que parece buena, pero no la votaste, no la aceptaste y tampoco dejaste comentarios en ella, en caso que no te estuviera funcionando. Quizás quieras re-hacer el [tour] para recordar como funciona el sitio o leer qué hacer cuando alguien responde. Un saludo.

Entiendo, pero no se que datos brindar...si no tengo nada, solamente el plugin que comente. No tengo ningun codigo ni nada, ni siquiera se como comenzar. :(

No soy experto en wordpress pero, siendo este un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de programación, usualmente estamos viendo y depurando código. Los módulos o plugins que mencionas, deben tener código y tú puedes depurarlo y aportar tus hallazgos a la pregunta (un [mcve] sería lo ideal).  Si no sabes como hacerlo, probablemente estás en el sitio equivocado. Sugiero, en todo caso, que vayas al soporte del fabricante de esos plugins, o que busques a un profesional calificado para realizar dicha tarea.

Hola, Bienvenid@ a [Es.so], tu pregunta es muy amplia ya que estas usando plugins externos, por favor lee [ask], aquí estamos para ayudar con problemas de código, mas no para hacer el trabajo o tarea de otros, te invito a hacer el [tour] y a leer como hacer un [example]
